# how to use broyden1 algorithm to calculate an exponential value

Tags: python, variables, optimization, scipy, exponential

I have to find the temperature in the equation:

```
u = 1.2*e^(-.025*T)
u = viscosity in N*s/m^2

T = degree C
```

using

```
scipy.optimize.broyden1()
```

how would you use that to find the T when u=.001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the broyden1 function, just give it the function that you want the root to be found and also an initial value. If you are only interested in solving for u=.001, you can just define a function that take T as an input. If you might want to change the value of u, partial might be a handy tool.

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def findtemp(T, u):
    return u - 1.2 * np.exp(-.025*T)

sol = scipy.optimize.broyden1(partial(findtemp, u=.001), 0)
print(sol)
```

gives me a value of 283.4828690696808 which is close to the theoretical value.